# How should I test HTML generated for a web page?

Tags: html, unit-testing, selenium, html-table

I have some HTML on a page that has a bunch of tables and data (it's a report page).  This is all legacy code, so no harassment necessary on the use of tables.

Given that it is legacy code, it is fragile, and we want to confirm that the table looks like we want (number of columns, rows, and the data inside of them are accurate).

My first inclination is to use selenium web driver and run through everything that way (Page Object Pattern), but a co-worker suggested that I just view source of the page, copy the table in question, and then just use this to do a string comparison in the test.

My initial thoughts on his proposal is that it is not a good test because you're starting with the answer and then writing a test to make sure you get that answer (essentially non-TDD).  But I'm not sure that's a good enough answer in this case.

How should I test HTML table to make sure all columns, rows are how we like, in addition to the contents of each cell?

Comment: Of course this is not going to be TDD, you are trying to retro-actively add testing to legacy code.

Comment: You are correct, sir.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  String matching sounds like [Approval Testing](https://github.com/approvals), depending on just how dynamic the table is that could be fine.

If I already had Selenium tests running I'ld stick with what I have.  Using findElements to count and verify the various columns, rows, and values.

Re: your comment if you cannot convince the developers to add ids, names, or something to make your job easier and you do go the Selenium route then xpath is probably what you will want to use.  We've created utility methods to help in these sort of situations:

```
public boolean isLabeledTextPresent(String label, String text) {
    WebElement element = findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th/label[contains(text(), '" +
        label + "')]/ancestor::tr/td"));
    String labeledText = element.getText().trim();
    return labeledText.contains(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @EGHM.  The other issue is that the table does not have any ID, name, or nameClass to easily grab via the find element functionality.  So I would then need to utilize xpath to traverse these tables (each entry in the report is its own table, so there could be scores of them).

Comment: @SeanLon11 Indeed, I updated my answer with an example of one of the techniques we use.

Answer (score 0):

I think both methods are valid, it really depends on what you are trying to do and what advantages/disadvantages work best for you.

1. It would take a little work (depending on you or your teammates skill sets and experience) to write a Selenium script to scrape the table and verify certain things.

Advantages:
Once completed, it will validate very quickly and will be less fragile than method #2.

Disadvantages:
This is dependent on how quickly you can write a script and how easily you are able to validate all the things you want to validate. If all you want is # cols/rows and cell content, that should be very easy. If you want to validate things like formatting (size, color, etc.) then that starts to get a little more complicated to do through code.

2. It would be super easy to copy/paste HTML and validate against that. The problem is, as you pointed out, you are starting with the answer in some respects. You can get around that by validating that the HTML source for the table is correct. That will have to be done manually but once you get that, you can open the page and compare source of the table vs what you have validated.

Advantages:
You will be able to tell when *anything* changes... formatting, data, # cells, ... everything.

Disadvantages:
You will be able to tell when *anything* changes... lol. Your test will fail when anything is changed which will make the test very fragile if you expect that the table will ever get updated. If it gets updated, you will have to revalidate all the HTML for the table which could get to be a tedious process depending how often you expect this to happen. One thing that will help with this validation is to use a diffing tool... you can quickly determine what has changed and validate that instead of having to validate everything each time there is a change.

I would lean towards #1, write the script. It will be less fragile and as long as someone has the right skills shouldn't be that big of a task.

---

EDIT

You didn't specify what language you are working in but here's some code in Java that hopefully will point you in the right direction if you choose to write a script.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(...));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
Assert("Validate expected number of rows", rows.size(), expectedNoOfRows);
for (int row = 0; row < rows.size(); row++)
{
    List<WebElement> cells = rows.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    Assert("Validate expected number of cells in row " + row, cells.size(), expectedNoOfCells[row]);
    for (int cell = 0; cell < cells.size(); cell++)
    {
        Assert("Validate expected text in (" + cell + "," + row + ")", cells.get(cell).getText().trim(), expectedText[cell][row]);
    }
}
```

You could do something like this at a basic level. If you want to get more fancy, you could add logic that looks for specific parts of the report so you can get a "landmark", e.g. Summary, Data, ... making headings up ... so you will know what to expect in the next section.

You could run a variation of this code to dump the different values, number of rows, number of cells in each row, and cell contents. Once you validate that those values are correct, you could use that as your master and do comparisons vs it. That will keep you from false fails on comparing straight HTML source. Maybe it's something in the middle between a script and text comparison based on HTML source.

Comment: good info @JeffC, and I appreciate the answer.  Given that we have no easy way to traverse the elements in the tables (xpath option only, or update the table code to contain ids, name, or nameClass, which could be messy), I'm leaning towards just doing a string comparison and then readdress as needed for future tests.

Comment: How many tables do you have on the page? If you don't have that many, you can grab the TABLE HTML tag and go from there easily.

Comment: In the test scenario, I'll populate the DB to where there are only a few results in the report.  The table's complexity lies in the merging of columns in rows in certain areas but not others, along with not having any ids to easily traverse for each of the <td> rows (e.g. <td id="firstName">, etc.).

Comment: OK. I added some code that hopefully will help you get your bearings in an HTML table using Selenium